# c++: #include and different file types

Tags: c++

I somehow can't grab the idea and reading the documentation hasn't helped me.

My questions are:

1. When I include a header file #include "general.h", and in the directory of my project there are two files general.h and general.cpp, does it mean that I the precompiler will find the .cpp file automatically?
2. Can I include files without extentions: #include "general"?
3. Can I include a file without any header file: #include "general.cpp"?
4. Can I include a txt file: #include "general.txt"?

I tried this all in Visual Studio 2010. No syntax errors at least. But I'd like to have an explanation. So, I hope you will be kind and help me.

Comment: @jonhopkins Woops, I look like an idiot.

Comment: For 1., the preprocessor won't include the .cpp automatically, but with some compilers (Oracle for instance) if the compiler finds declarations in the .h file and wants the corresponding definitions, it may try to compile a .cc or .cpp file matching the name of the .h file. This is mostly very confusing in practice and should be avoided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. No, the precompiler know nothing about the .cpp file
2. Yes, if the file has no extensions
3. You can include any file you want. It doesn't mean you will get anything useful out of it.
4. See point 3. above.

Answer (score 6):

The standard and the compiler don't really care much about whether a file is `.cpp` or `.h` or `.monkeyface`. The concepts behind structuring your source code into implementation and header files are really just accepted ways to help manage your source. Despite this, not structuring your source in the accepted way is often considered to be incorrect or bad C++.

All `#include` does is tell the preprocessor to include the contents of the file you specify in the current file. It's like copying and pasting the other file into yours. When you say `#include "foo.h"`, it just includes the contents of `foo.h` and doesn't care about `foo.cpp` at all - it doesn't even know that it exists (and there's no reason it has to exist).

Structuring your source code in implementation and header files is extremely useful - it avoids problems with dependencies and multiple definitions, and also improves compilation time somewhat. When your code uses another class, you only need to `#include` the header file for that class. The reason is because your code doesn't need to care about the implementation of the class, it just needs to know what it looks like (its name, members, base class, etc.). It doesn't concern itself with how exactly the member functions are implemented.

The extensions `.cpp` and `.h` are merely conventions. Some people prefer to use `.hpp` for header files. Some people even use `.tpp` for template implementations. You can name them however you like - yes, you can even include a `.txt` file. Your compiler probably tries to infer things about files (for example, which language to compile it as) from the file extension, but that is usually overrideable.

So if your `main.cpp` includes `foo.h` because it uses class `foo`, at what point does `foo.cpp` get involved? Well, in the compilation of `main.cpp`, it doesn't get involved at all. `main.cpp` doesn't need to know about the implementation of the class, as we discussed above. However, when compiling your entire program, you will pass each of your `.cpp` files to the compiler to be compiled separately. That is, you would do something like `g++ main.cpp foo.cpp`. When `foo.cpp` is compiled, it will include the headers that *it* needs to compile.

After each of your `.cpp` files has been compiled (which involves including the headers that they depend on), they are then linked together. The use of a member function `foo::bar()` in `main.cpp` will at this stage be linked to the implementation of `foo::bar()` that was given in `foo.cpp`.

Answer (score 1):

The `#include` directive tells the preprocessor to read the file. That's all.

Comment: It does more with it than just "read it": it actually *inserts* the entire contents of the file that is being included. With a *potential* exception for the C++ standard library headers, which the compiler can internally handle in any way it wants.

Comment: @NikBougalis - more detailed descriptions are certainly possible, but it would be silly to interpret "read the file" to mean "read the file and ignore its contents".

Answer (score 1):

The preprocessor simply inserts the whole content of the given file when it encounters a #include directive.

Answer (score 0):

`#include` is a simple "insert the contents of the given file here" mechanism, so the preprocessor will include exactly the file you specify. If you include a .h file, neither the preprocessor nor the compiler will know about the corresponding .cpp file - each .cpp file is compiled separately (the purpose of the .h files is to inform the compiler of which functions exist outside of the current .cpp file). After compilation, the *linker* is invoked, and only then are the compiled results of the different .cpp files combined.